# How to create link to google map with opened info and window

Tags: google-maps

I need to create link on google maps with marker + infowindow 
I found this link:

url http://www.google.com/maps?q=41.0082,28.9784(INFO_WINDOW)

used to work before. But now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That is the "old"/"classic" Google Maps, it no longer works.

Some options:

1. Look at the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed)
2. Create a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map of your own that supports that functionality ([example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?id=Marker%20Two))

Comment: I need standalone link , without using google maps on web site.